# php simple countdown

Tags: php, countdown

I have a date like `3/3/2012 10:56:34` and i'd like to convert it to a countdown (like ebay).

It doesn't have to be dynamic, just something like

```
3h 2m
2d 4h
3m
```

etc

It doesn't have to show years, just days, hours, mins, secs, whichever is applicable.

So if there's over a day to go, it'll show days and hours, if under a day, just hours mins, if under an hour, just mins.

Is there a simple way to do this?

### UPDATE

This is what I have, but doesn't work (fixed)

```
$timediff = round(strtotime($rs[ends]) - strtotime($now));

while ($timediff > 86400) { $timediff = $timediff - 86400; $days++; }
while ($timediff > 3600) { $timediff = $timediff - 3600; $hours++; }
while ($timediff > 60) { $timediff = $timediff - 60; $mins++; }
$secs = $timediff;

echo $days . "d " . $hours . "h " .$mins . "m";
```

Comment: from a mysql date/time field. And Mark B, yes, a cuppa. One sugar.

Comment: What @MarcB is getting at is that SO doesn't exist for you to get free code. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: fair enough, updated with my code that doesnt work

Comment: 2 correct answers below you have ignored? -1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert your string to the Unix timestamp, then calculate the difference between now and the timestamp and then you'll easily manage to extract days, hours, minutes, etc...

Example for secs and mins from the top of my head (applicable for $timediff < 1 hour, in your case):

`$seconds = $timediff % 60; $minutes = floor($timediff / 60);`

etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

first use strtotime to convert to the unix time stamp if necessary.

simply calculate the times you want it to count down by:

```
1day is 86400 seconds.
1hour is 3600 seconds
```

Use SQL to get the time stamp then simply if and ifelse statements.

```
$currenttime=time();

if($currenttime-$somearray[0][time_stamp]<3600)
{
    $seconds=$curenttime-$somearray;
    echo"$seconds seconds ago";
}
elseif($currenttime-$somearray[0][time_stamp}<86400)
{
    $seconds=$currenttime-$somearray;
    $minutes=floor($seconds/60);
    echo"$minutes minutes ago";
}
```

and just continue the elseif statements for whatever intervals you would like.